# MS Access VBA made on Windows 7 fails on Windows 8

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba

I am having a very frustrating issue which im not able to resolve.

I have created a database program on windows 7 which i am not able to run on Windows 8. The error i receive is "Error communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control".

To test out what is causing it i have erased VBA code and the program has started successfully. To test it out even further I have created an empty database with 1 form and vba code for a simple messagebox (Windows 7) and it has failed me on windows 8 again, same error message.

Any help would be appreciated , because google isn't helping me

EDIT: Computer language is English, Keyboard language English/Lithuanian, Region Lithuania, VBA font Arial(Baltic) tested all these as well but didn't seem to fix my issue

EDIT2: I have identified the problem , it actually is System Locale, Windows 7 computer is using system locale - Lithuania, Windows 8 is using English (US). Does anyone know how to solve this problem? my company has multiple windows 7 and windows 8 computers, changing locale is not an option

Comment: Check your VBA references under Tools in the IDE. Your code is calling some object that program has no associated reference. See if you have [Visual Basic and other defaults](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/questions/vba_reference2013.php) enabled.

Comment: All defaults are enabled, creating a new empty file on windows 8 uses same default references, tried playing around with different versions, no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is the versions of the various DLLs that your VBA code uses.

In the VB editor Go into Tools/References on Windows 8 and see if there any library references that it can't find.  Then look at the list below and see if you can select a later version to fix it.